# navigation bar is missing after segue

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a table view controller, and in that I have a search bar attached to the header.

```
tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController?.searchBar
```

when I type words into the search bar, my post is retrieved from Firebase and is displayed in another table called segueTableViewController

```
 let locationSearchTable = UIStoryboard(name: "MainPage", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SegueTableViewController") as! SegueTableViewController
        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: locationSearchTable)
        searchController?.searchResultsUpdater = locationSearchTable
```

When I click the cells in segueTableViewController, it segues me to a detailed page but this page does not have a navigation bar. However, when I segue from another page to the detailed page it has a navigation bar. I have been trying to figure out why for months and I can't.
[image]

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "GOTOPOST" {

            if let IndexPaths = self.followUsersTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {

                self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false

                let vc = segue.destination as! BookDetailsViewController
}}}
```

Comment: What is the presentation type of your segue in the storyboard? There should be a circle in the center of the line connecting the view controllers with an icon in the middle representing the type.

Comment: @Callam show segue

Comment: Okay, please can you add a screenshot of your storyboard including the navigation controller, as well the code you have for performing the segue?

Comment: Could this be a bug? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please add storyboard relationship(show). And storyboard add identifier value "SegueTableViewController". Navigation controller should be in Search storyboard referans

[image]

Comment: that's what I did initially

Comment: Navigation controller should be in Search storyboard referans

Comment: try this code "self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)" add viewWillDisappear

Comment: I have that as well

Comment: do you have a navigationControl in search reference ?

Comment: yes, I have a navigation controller attached to the search controller. The initial view controller is the (HomeViewController)HV. there is a search bar on HV and when I search, the results are displayed in (ResultsViewController) RV but just the table view of RV and then when I click on a cell it segues to (DetaledViewController) DV and that's where I lose the navigation bar.